# transfer a variable from valuechanged method to actionperformed

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton, jlist

i need to transfer one variable from the `valuechanged` method to `actionperformed` method. The variable that i need to be trasfered is "index", so that i can use it as an index for an array. can someone please tell me how to do it?

```
public class ListHandler implements ListSelectionListener 
    {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event)
                    {

                            if (event.getSource().equals("Check")) 
                            {

                                int index = material.getSelectedIndex();//VARIABLE      NEEDED TO BE TRANSFERED

                            }
                    }
    }

    public class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                    {

                        v=Double.parseDouble(vtext.getText());
                        e1=E1(v, v1[index], v2[index]);
                        e2=E2(v, v1[index], v2[index]);
                        e1text.setText(Double.toString(e1));
                        e2text.setText(Double.toString(e2));

                    }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the scope the variable. Make it as instance member. That solves your problem.

As of now `index`  scope is restricted to the method `valueChanged()`. So move the declaration to instance level and assign value in `valueChanged()` method. So that you can use the same `index` variable in `actionPerformed()` method as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple design.

Move the code of the action listener into a method as shown below as pass the index.

```
public void doActionPerformed(int index){
    // action performed code goes here
    // check the index value before doing any operation on it
}
```

and simply call it from

```
if (event.getSource().equals("Check")) {
      int index = material.getSelectedIndex();
      doActionPerformed(index);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
     doActionPerformed(-1);
}
```

---

#### EDIT

you can try a very simple way

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
     int index = material.getSelectedIndex();
     ...
}
```